# Variable return con p en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios

Tengo un código que hace un checking del password y si este es corto, imprime lo correspondiente.
Mi problema es que tengo la variable return y necesito que esta imprima un texto envuelto en `<p>...</p>`, pero no se muy bien como hacer. Aquí os dejo el código.

```
 $('#password').keyup(function () {
    $('#result').html(checkStrength($('#password').val()))
})

function checkStrength(password) {
    var strength = 0
    if (password.length < 6) {
        $('#result').removeClass()
        $('#result').css("background-color", "red"),
        return 'Too short'
    }
    if (password.length > 7) strength += 1

    if (password.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/)) strength += 1

    if (password.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && password.match(/([0-9])/)) strength += 1

    if (password.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength += 1

    if (password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~].*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength += 1

    if (strength < 2) {
        $('#result').removeClass(),
        $('#result').css("background-color" , "orange")
        return 'Weak'
    } else if (strength == 2) {
        $('#result').removeClass()
        $('#result').css("background-color", "green")
        return 'Good'
    } else {
        $('#result').removeClass()
        $('#result').css("background-color", "var(--jobcafe-grün)")
        return 'Strong'
    }
}
```

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar. 
Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has probado, simplemente, a poner `return '<p>Too short</p>'`?

Funciona bien, aquí tienes un ejemplo con tu código:

```js
$('#password').keyup(function () {
    $('#result').html(checkStrength($('#password').val()))
})

function checkStrength(password) {
    var strength = 0
    if (password.length < 6) {
        $('#result').removeClass();
        $('#result').css("background-color", "red");
        return '<p>Too short</p><p>muy corta</p>'
    }
    if (password.length > 7) strength += 1

    if (password.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/)) strength += 1

    if (password.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && password.match(/([0-9])/)) strength += 1

    if (password.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength += 1

    if (password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~].*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength += 1

    if (strength < 2) {
        $('#result').removeClass(),
        $('#result').css("background-color" , "orange")
        return 'Weak'
    } else if (strength == 2) {
        $('#result').removeClass()
        $('#result').css("background-color", "green")
        return 'Good'
    } else {
        $('#result').removeClass()
        $('#result').css("background-color", "var(--jobcafe-grün)")
        return 'Strong'
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" id="password" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Cuál es el motivo de querer devolverlo envuelto en un elemento p? ¿Podrías probar esto?

```
$('#result').html(`<p>${checkStrength( $('#password').val() )}</p>`);
```

Es para que la función de comprobar la fortaleza sólo haga eso, no tenga que entender de HTML (lo que sería un buen principio de diseño, que puedes consultar aquí: [SRP o Principio de Responsabilidad Única](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica).

De ese modo, la función checkStrengh también se vuelve más fácil de testear, sobre todo cuando el flujo pase por una contraseña corta o débil, y no tienes que mezclar con código HTML.